# parse_str and ajax and sql injection

Tags: php, ajax, serialization

I want post data with ajax to the php file.
I  write this code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'ajax-processor.php',
            data: {
                ser: $('#user_new').serialize(),  //#user_new is form
                actioncode: 25,
                mobile: 911111111
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (responce) {

                }
```

and in **php** file

```
 if (isset($_POST['ser'])) {
        $serArray = array();
        parse_str($_POST['ser'], $serArray);
```

Doing `echo  $serArray` return an empty Array
What is problem?
What is the **best way of get data that sent whit serialize jquery in php file** as a  object?

Also, **is secure use `$serArray` in query mysql whit out any change?**

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the function `json_decode()`

Answer (score 0):

i do this

```
parse_str(urldecode($_POST['ser']),$serArray);
```

and get value

```
$fname = $serArray['fname'];
```

and

```
$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($fname);
```

to send to mysql